# Take last-child instead of first-child on the only table row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

I have following CSS:

```
table tbody tr:last-child td {
  padding-top: 7px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td {
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

Now I may have a table with just one row.
The only table row is now assigned to `first-child` instead of `last-child`, but I want it to be the other way around.

Is there a way without Javascript?

Comment: "How can I assign last-child to all <td> instead of first-child"? could you rephrase this? where you defined a border-bottom ?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you tried `border-bottom:none;` and `border-bottom:0px;`?

Comment: @poepje: It doesn't affect the table row, because, as I see in the developer console, `first-child` is assigned to the row. @ F. Calderan: I try to, but it's somehow hard for me to explain.

Comment: What if you just invert the rule order so that `last-child` rule should take the precedence?

Comment: @F.Calderan: Unfortunately that has no effect at all.

Comment: so please post a fiddle and show a simple example if you can

Comment: @F.Calderan: Ah I see the problem now, it's affected by the `quicksearch` plugin for jQuery, which changes it dynamically. :( So it's depending on that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be. You must have some mistake in your markup. If it really is the only `tr`, both `last` AND `first` will match.

**[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/FEgZE/)**

However, which CSS will be applied depends on the order of you css-rules. So you can determine whether `padding-top: 7px;` `or padding-top: 6px;` shall applie by placing the rules accordingly.

edit:

as your problem is caused by a plugin, which inserts a row automatically at the end, you can simply use `:nth-last-child(2)` to match the second-last element. 
<sub>(Note however that Browser-support for `nth-last-child` is slightly worse than `last-child`)</sub>

Comment: Yes, but he has the same style "padding-bottom" at :first-child and :last-child. So one of this rules will be only applied. It will work for diffrent styles, as in your example e.g. background and border.

Comment: You are right it was my mistake. As I said in Sófkas reply, it was the fault of an plugin. I think I need to hack something in there now.

Comment: @Sófka you can solve that by switching the css-rules. His problem was, that only on selector applied, which was definitely an error.

Comment: @Dan Now that you know, that the plugin inserts a row at the end, just take `:nth-last-child(2)` - this will match the second-last row;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a rule which will be only if tr is first-child and last-child at the same time, and this `table tbody tr:first-child:last-child td` add to the same styles as `table tbody tr:last-child td`. It will gonna look like this:

```
table tbody tr:last-child td,
table tbody tr:first-child:last-child td{
  padding-top: 7px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}​
```

Here seems to work :) -
http://jsfiddle.net/HjZU4/

Comment: I found out the source of the problem. It's kind of tricky because it's triggered by a plugin for jQuery. Thanks anyway :)